# Using makefile wildcard command for file names with spaces

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that I use to compress pictures:

```
src=$(wildcard Photos/*.jpg) $(wildcard Photos/*.JPG)
out=$(subst Photos,Compressed,$(src))

all : $(out)

clean:
    @rmdir -r Compressed

Compressed:
    @mkdir Compressed

Compressed/%.jpg: Photos/%.jpg Compressed
    @echo "Compressing $<"
    @convert "$<" -scale 20% "$@"

Compressed/%.JPG: Photos/%.JPG Compressed
    @echo "Compressing $<"
    @convert "$<" -scale 20% "$@"
```

However, when I have a picture with a space in its name, for example `Piper PA-28-236 Dakota.JPG`, I get this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Compressed/Piper', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I think this is a problem in the `wildcard` command, but I'm not sure what to change to get it to work.

**How can I modify my makefile to allow for spaces in file names?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally having spaces in file names is a bad idea with make, but for your case this may work:

```
src=$(shell find Photos/ -iname '*.JPG' | sed 's/ /\\ /g')

out=$(subst Photos,Compressed,$(src))

all : $(out)

Compressed:
  @mkdir Compressed

Compressed/%: Photos/% Compressed
  @echo "Compressing $<"
  @convert "$<" -scale 20% "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works to fix the spaces in the wildcard problem. I modified it to `src=$(shell ls Photos | sed 's/ /\\ /g;s/.*/Photos\/\0/')` to allow `JPG` and `jpg`. However, now I'm getting the error `make: *** No rule to make target 'Compressed/Piper PA-28-236 Dakota.JPG', needed by 'all'.  Stop.` So now I need to figure out how to get targets with spaces to work.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for all your help. Replacing with a `?` fixes the targets issue, but added a `?` in the resulting file. I ended up using a call function: `replace = echo $(1) | sed 's/?/ /g'` and then used it with this command: `@convert "$<" -scale 20% "\`$(call replace,$@)\`"`

Comment: Should I accept your answer or should I create my own answer detailing all I did to get it to work, showing the final Makefile?

Comment: Hmmm, when I add a new image to the `Photos` directory or delete one of the compressed images from the `Compressed` directory, the Makefile compresses ALL the pictures, not just the new one or the one with out a compressed version.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, it is much simpler. However, the problem I described in my last comment still happens.

Comment: @iBelieve, if you make twice in a row, without adding or removing any photos, does it compress and recompress all pictures? Or all space-named pictures? Perhaps GNU Make is using the space-unsafe variables $^ and $? internally to keep tabs on which prerequisites are new, failing, and assuming that all prerequisites are new. That's a bug in GNU Make that can be fixed in a backwards-compatible manner.

Comment: Never mind, I tested a similar setup but named the targets without spaces in filenames even though the prerequisite filenames contained spaces, and GNU Make 4.3 did not rebuild when unnecessary.